# MySQL using LEFT JOIN to query on all records not just one

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using MySQL and a LEFT JOIN with a sub select. In any case the way I currently have it set up, I am having to hard code in the value "ELO-250030" that I am querying on. I want to be able to run this script without having to hardcode in my value or pass it into the query, I just want the sql query to loop over all the records in the db table and match up where I currently have "ELO-250030". For instance, if I have a sku of ELO-250030, ELO-250031, ELO-250032. It needs to query for each of these values. How do I set up my query below so that I can remove:

```
AND fbas.sku = 'ELO-250030'
```

and

```
AND fbai.sku = 'ELO-250030'
```

but MySQL will still match up these columns and queries...

Here is my entire sql query.

```
SELECT  fbai.id, 
    fbai.sku,
    sumQS, 
    SUM(fbai.qtyFulfillable) AS sumQF
FROM    FBAInventory fbai
LEFT JOIN 
   (
        SELECT fbas.sku, SUM(fbas.quantityShipped) as sumQS
        FROM FBAShipment fbas
        WHERE fbas.shipmentDate BETWEEN '2014-08-15 22:19:50' AND '2014-09-15 01:10:57'
        AND fbas.sku = 'ELO-250030'
    ) fbas ON fbai.sku = fbas.sku
WHERE   fbai.fbaInventoryReport_id = 62010
AND     fbai.sku = 'ELO-250030'
GROUP BY fbai.id
ORDER BY sumQF DESC;
```

I've tried doing this but I just get errors:

```
SELECT  fbai.id, 
    fbai.sku,
    sumQS, 
    SUM(fbai.qtyFulfillable) AS sumQF
FROM    FBAInventory fbai
LEFT JOIN 
   (
        SELECT fbas.sku, SUM(fbas.quantityShipped) as sumQS
        FROM FBAShipment fbas
        WHERE fbas.shipmentDate BETWEEN '2014-08-15 22:19:50' AND '2014-09-15 01:10:57'
        AND fbas.sku = fbai.sku
    ) fbas ON fbai.sku = fbas.sku
WHERE   fbai.fbaInventoryReport_id = 62010
GROUP BY fbai.sku
ORDER BY sumQF DESC;
```

Comment: remove the two lines in question and change your group by `GROUP BY fbai.sku`

Comment: When I do what you suggested, my "sumQS" column is NULL for all records

Comment: How are you planning to pass the value `ELO-250030` to the query? From where this values coming?

Comment: Consider providing sample data set for your table and their structures in sql fiddle and also add expected result set in your question

Comment: I will not be passing in the value "ELO-250030", this value is just one of thousands in each of the tables being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the left join and subquery in select clause are fine for solution.

For example

```
SELECT  
  fbai.id, 
  fbai.sku,
  (
        SELECT SUM(fbas.quantityShipped) as sumQS
        FROM FBAShipment fbas
        WHERE fbas.sku = fbai.sku
            AND fbas.shipmentDate BETWEEN '2014-08-15 22:19:50' AND '2014-09-15 01:10:57'
    ) sumQS, 
  SUM(fbai.qtyFulfillable) AS sumQF
FROM    FBAInventory fbai
WHERE   fbai.fbaInventoryReport_id = 62010
GROUP BY fbai.id, fbai.sku
ORDER BY 4;
```

Comment: I need to be able to run this query without having to use this line: AND fbai.sku = 'ELO-250030' or this line: AND fbas.sku = 'ELO-250030'.

Comment: I ve tried doing this but I just get errors: (
        SELECT SUM(fbas.quantityShipped) as sumQS
        FROM FBAShipment fbas
        WHERE fbas.sku = fbai.sku
            AND fbas.shipmentDate BETWEEN '2014-08-15 22:19:50' AND '2014-09-15 01:10:57' AND fbai.sku = fbas.sku

    ) sumQS,

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the issue is, you are still assuming that I am passing in the variable "ELO-250030", which I do not want to have to do. I want the first query to insert the value into the sub query. So basically the sub query will inherit every sku value as the query runs and then output the results.

Comment: Elliminated the constant now from filter.

Comment: Thats it! It works great, not sure what the ORDER BY 4 is? Can I just use ORDER BY sumQf DESC instead?

Comment: It is not working with alias, the alternative is to write the whole subquery, but I would not suggest it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your group by is messed...any other SQL engine will error out on your query (as it should), but MySQL loves ignoring it and doing the wrong thing instead...best solution is to uninstall MySQL and use a better database.

Failing that, cmorrissey's comment is actually correct for an answer had your group by been correct:

Change your group by to:
    fbai.id, 
    fbai.sku,
    sumQS

remove the SKU references.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are specifically filtering out for different/specific SKU number then you can just do a join between the tables for matching SKU. Something like below.

```
SELECT  fbai.id, 
        fbai.sku,
        fbas.sumQS,
        fbai.sumQF
FROM
(
  SELECT id,
         sku, 
         SUM(qtyFulfillable) as sumQF
  FROM  FBAInventory 
  WHERE fbaInventoryReport_id = 62010
  GROUP BY id, sku
) fbai
LEFT JOIN 
   (
        SELECT sku, SUM(quantityShipped) as sumQS
        FROM FBAShipment
        WHERE fbas.shipmentDate 
        BETWEEN '2014-08-15 22:19:50' AND '2014-09-15 01:10:57'
        GROUP BY sku       
    ) fbas 
ON fbai.sku = fbas.sku
ORDER BY fbai.sumQF DESC;
```

Comment: This still returns all the sumQS as NULL

Comment: Almost there, now the sumQf is showing 1615 instead of 85 :( thanks for you help by the way

Comment: That's why you should clear everything in your post beforehand. Check the edit; I think this is what you are looking.